# Access Session Object

Tags: c#, session

I develop a `DLL` using `C#`.

I create an installer that allows the user to select where the program directory will be installed.

I would like to use the path of selected install directory, therefore I need to access `session["INSTALLDIR"]` value.

How can I access the session object no from an ASP project?

Comment: Why is "INSTALLDIR" in Session?  How does the user input the desired install path?

Comment: @Tim, Thanks. The installer allows the user to browse for location to install. Now I would like to retrieve this data. Can I do it in any other way?

Comment: I've never built an installer, but I would expect you're using some sort of dialog, so you should be able to capture that information from the dialog and use it later in your application.  Without seeing more code I can't really say.

Comment: @Tim, you are right: there is a dialog that allows to select the desired directory. However, I cannot retrieve the data from it. Any other ideas?

Comment: You need to use `System.Web` and can access session by `HttpContext.Current.Session["INSTALLDIR"]`. But you may also need to use `IRequiresSessionState` interface for your class in order to access session object. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx

Comment: @Bharadwaj, Thanks. It is not ASP.Net so I cannot use the session properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it windows form application?

Comment: @Bharadwaj, No, it is a DLL.

Comment: DLL used in web application?

Comment: @Bharadwaj No, It is a class library c# project. No connection to ASP at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a VS deployment project than INSTALLDIR can be retried in [Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx) by using

> Context.Parameters["INSTALLDIR"]

Comment: Schnieder, Thanks. What is the context object?

Comment: Click on the link in the answer.